# Static property of swift framework becomes null in xamarin binding

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin, dll, objective-sharpie

I developed a swift framework as xcframework & created xamarin binding for it. In the framework the call is made as a singleton class

```
MyFramework.shared.start()
```

The shared is a singleton instance

```
static let shared = MyFramework()
```

After making dll in Xamarin and calling the start method it crashes because shared in null. The `ApiDefinition.cs` file is provided below. Can someone help on how to make the shared instance allocated.

```
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

// @interface LeapCreator : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject), Name = "_TtC14MyFrameworkSDK11MyFramework")]
[Protocol]
interface MyFramework
{
    // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong, class) MyFramework * _Nonnull shared;
    [Static]
    [Export("shared", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
    MyFramework Shared { get; }

    // -(void)start:(NSString * _Nonnull)apiKey;
    [Export("start:")]
    void Start(string apiKey);
}
```

Comment: Did you check that the method is correct in your swift code? Whether the return value of the method is empty？

Comment: Yes. The code is working as expected in swift code.